# Apache not starting via Webmin but works via apachectl in the terminal

Tags: apache-http-server, webmin

I am having issues with Apache and Webmin.

Whenever I try to start the Apache server through Webmin it throws an error:

```
Error thrown when pressing start button
```

I am using an AWS EC2 using their Linux also. I've ran the `apachectl` commands and they seem to work fine and I can start the webserver. But it's not picking up the VHosts that I've set up.